# how to set force login to google javascript api?

Tags: javascript, google-authentication, google-signin

I am following the instructions in
 https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#sign_out_a_user
But once logged out, it is signing out from my application and not completely from google. Next time when logging in without asking the credentials it logs into the last logged in account. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your user opens https://accounts.google.com/logout

I'd suggest an invisible iframe.

Best,